# App Store and Enable App Sandoxing

Tags: macos, app-store, sandbox

In the Summary of my targets I have noticed that there is a `App Sandbox [ ] Enable App Sandboxing` option.

Does this need to be checked for my mac app to be accepted into the App Store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: ["App Sandboxing, a requirement for all apps submitted to the Mac App Store"](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/checklist/)